# How to "reset" gsl::owner<T>?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

When I create an object and append it to a list

```
auto o = new object;
m_objects.push_back(o);
```

I get several hints from the compiler that I should clean up my code along the C++ Core Check guidelines, among them

- do not use `new` and `delete` directly, use `unique_ptr` (VC++ warning C26409)
- reset or explicitly `delete` an `owner<T>` pointer (VC++ warning 26403)

The latter intrigues me: how am I supposed to "reset" this pointer so the compiler does not warn me here, given that I've transferred ownership to the `list`? Assigning `nullptr` gives me an additional warning

- do not assign to an `owner<T>` that may be in a valid state (VC++ warning 26405)

and doesn't clear up the original complaint, so that's not it.

Comment: Before the list goes out of scope, or whenever you remove an item from the list, or reassign an item in the list, you have to call `delete` on the pointer. `m_objects` will call destructors for all objects contained in it when it is destroyed, but pointers don't have destructors.

Comment: you have a list of pointers, not a list of object, ie the list does not own the objects

Comment: What is the type of `m_objects`? `std::list<object*>`?

Comment: Ah, so `std::list<gsl::owner<object *>>` would make `push_back` take an owner pointer, which would transfer ownership and be counted as a "reset" from the checker's point of view?

Comment: Can you pldase show your code with `gsl::owner` that triggers the warning!? And can you please share which VC version you are using!?

Comment: When possible use the `std::unique_ptr`. Only when it is not possible use `gsl::owner`. Compare http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i11-never-transfer-ownership-by-a-raw-pointer-t-or-reference-t.

Answer (score 0):

> warning C26403: Reset or explicitly delete an owner pointer 'p'
> (r.3).

Both parts ("reset" and "explicitly delete") can be seen in this example:

```
gsl::owner<char*> p = new char{}; // take ownership
gsl::owner<char*> q = p;          // copy ownership -> problem
p = nullptr;                      // p is reset to release ownership
delete q;                         // second is owner, needs explicit delete
```

`p` is copied to `q` and then reset so that only one owner exists.
`q` is explicitly deleted.

Just resetting without giving away ownership like in

```
gsl::owner<char*> p = new char{};
p = nullptr;
```

is of course a memory leak and thus justifies the

> warning C26405: Do not assign to an owner which may be in valid state (r.3).